# Can I use the same Thymeleaf fragment modal in the same page but with different parameters?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I have a side with card. The cards have different headlines and content. By clicking on the cards a modal opens with the specific text from the card. But when I try it, always the parameters from the first fragment call are used.

This is my code:

Webside with cards, which calls the modal two times:

```
<!-- First Card -->
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-md-4 mb-lg-5 pe-4 ps-4">
             <div th:insert="fragments/Modal_Card :: Modal_Card('Text 1', 'Headline1')"></div>
                    <div class="card shadow text-white h-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#Modal_Card" style="background-color: var(--own-green-2); border-radius: 1rem">
                        <div class="card-body px-5 h-100">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <i class="bi bi-pc-display" style="font-size: 2.5rem;"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col mt-auto mb-auto">
                                    Headline1
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-3 pb-3">
                                <hr class="mb-3">
                                Text1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Second Card -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-md-4 mb-lg-5 pe-4 ps-4">
                  <div th:include="fragments/Modal_Card :: Modal_Card('Text 2', 'Headline2')"></div>
                    <div class="card shadow text-white h-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="Modal_Card" style="background-color: var(--own-green-2); border-radius: 1rem">
                        <div class="card-body px-5 h-100">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <i class="bi bi-pc-display" style="font-size: 2.5rem;"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col mt-auto mb-auto">
                                    Headline2
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-3 pb-3">
                                <hr class="mb-3">
                                Text2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Fragment with Modal:

```
<div th:fragment="Modal_Card(content, headline)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true" id="Modal_Card">

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><span th:text="${headline}"></span></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p th:text="${content}"></p>



                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter which card i click the modal always have the parameters "Headline1" and "Text1". If someone know a solution please let me know.

Comment: The code in your question does not run - it throws an error because there is no `th:fragment` defined anywhere. I would expect to see `<div th:fragment="Modal_Card(content, headline)">` in your `fragments/Modal_Card.html` template - or something like that. When I add that to my version of your code, things work as I would expect - and I do not see the problem you are describing.

Comment: See the documentation for [Parameterizable Fragment Signatures](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures).

Comment: Oh Sorry this was my first post and somehow a part of the fragment code wasn't displayed... this code is missing:
<div th:fragment="Decarbonize_Modal_Card(content, headline)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true" id="Modal_Card">
.....
</div>

My code is running but the fragment never shows the Headline "Headline2" or "Text2", because i think it always uses the first fragment call withn the parameters "Headline1" and "Text1".

Comment: Isn't the problem that both modals have an id of `Modal_Card`? Maybe make that id also a fragment parameter so both modals can have different id's?

Comment: You were right, it worked thanks a lot Wim Deblauwe!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both modals have an `id` of `Modal_Card`. Add an extra parameter to your fragment and use `th:id` in the fragment so the id's become unique for each modal.

Something like this:

```
<div th:fragment="Modal_Card(content, headline, modalId)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true" th:id="${modalId}">
```

and use it like this:

```
<div th:insert="fragments/Modal_Card :: Modal_Card('Text 1', 'Headline1', 'Modal_Card_1')"></div>
```